# Prefix all elements names except for one which should be copied as-is

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to get an XSLT which will lowercase all element names and add a prefix to all of them except for an id field.   It's all working except the id field does not get copied.

Here is my XSLT

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="theprefix_{translate(local-name(), $uppercase, $lowercase)}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::unique_id)]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{translate(local-name(), $uppercase, $lowercase)}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `unique_id` in your XSLT sample, so I assume, you
want to keep just this element without any change (not `id`).

Add a template matching `unique_id`:

```
<xsl:template match="unique_id">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

and delete `[not(self::unique_id)]` from your code.

The added template is more specific than the template matching "*", so in
case of `unique_id` it "wins" and just it processes any `unique_id` node.

Comment: thanks, works like a champ.  I need to read up on how the template matching works.   I had no idea they fell through like that.